# Right Workflow for repetitive works on QGIS

Tags: workflow, qgis

I have to do some works about hydrology in QGIS. All works has the same common layers and a few results layers for each one.

I think to do a template QGIS file with common layers but I have a doubt.

I have organized the template in some groups:

- Layers

  - Layer Result A
  - Layer Result B
  - Layer Result C
  - Common Layer X
  - Common Layer Y
  - Common Layer Z
- Figures

  - Figure 1

    - Copy of Layer Result A
    - Copy of Common Layer X
  - Figure 2

    - Copy of Layer Result B
    - Copy of Common Layer Y
  - ...
- Plans

  - Plan 1

    - Copy of Layer Result A
    - Copy of common layer X
  - Plan 2

    - Copy of Layer Result B
    - Copy of Common Layer Y
  - ...

The question is, How I can update the result layers in each project and update automatically the copies of these layers?

Some workflow recommendation suggestion??

I tried the "update source file font" option existing in options layers menu and update the result layers well but I cannot update de copies or duplicated layers without update each time the source in the copied layer.